# Sleep mode on Mac OS X, don't wake up again

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

I have a MBP 13 (OSX El Capitan 10.11.2) with two external monitors. After a while when I do nothing my MBP switch to the sleep mode. The problem is that sometime it don't wake up again when I move the mouse or touch on the keyboard. I only get a black screen.

Anyone else have this type of issue?

What can I do?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Have your tried resetting the SMC?